# Code Signing Certificate Reputation with SmartScreen Filter

Tags: code-signing, authenticode, smartscreen

I am using a standard (i.e. not EV) Authenticode code signing certificate to sign a Windows desktop application in the hope that Smartscreen Filter will eventually stop blocking it.

I was hoping to [certify the application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637086(v=vs.85).aspx) but since my code signing certificate was issued by GoDaddy it appears that I can't do that since you need a certificate from [Symantec, Entrust, GlobalSign, WoSign or Digicert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh801887(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to create a Windows Certification Dashboard account (the first step in the certification process).

So here's my question: Will my non-certified Windows application signed with a standard GoDaddy SHA-2 code signing certificate still accumulate reputation?

Comment: You're making several incorrect assumptions in this question. 1. The first link for "_certify the application_" only applies if you converted your desktop app to UWP. There's a ton of restrictions, so most desktop apps will not quality. But that **is not** for helping your app from being blocked by the Smart Screen. 2. The second link is for Windows driver signing. And it's a totally different ballgame. 3. Lastly, to make that Smart Screen stop issuing warnings about your signed app, it has to be downloaded by multiple people and not reported as malware. That seems to be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to these article, most likely yes, but you need to check details in your certificate
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51151.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-as-of-january-30-2018.aspx